# Initializing static member makes compilation work... but why

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, definition, clang++

I have 3 files:

main.cpp -

```
#include "test.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    test x;
    return (1);
}
```

test.hpp -

```
#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP

class test
{
    static int a;

public:
    void    func(void);
};

#endif
```

test.cpp -

```
#include "test.hpp"

int test::a = 0; // removing this line makes compilation fail

void    test::func(void)
{
    a--;
}
```

and I compile with: `clang++ *.cpp -I .`, only these 3 files are in my directory.

the compilation fail message is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::a", referenced from:
      test::func() in test-8bbfc4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

from my understanding the line:

> ```
> int   test::a = 0; // removing this line makes compilation fail
> ```

was just initializing the static member `a` to 0, which as it is already 0 effectively means nothing.

Why should this make a difference for the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was just initializing the static member a to 0

No, it's not just initialization, it's the definition of the [static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Explanation). Without it you'll get the link error as you've seen.

> The declaration inside the class body is not a definition...

BTW: [Constant static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members)<sup>*</sup> and [inline static members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members) (since C++17) can be defined in the class definition.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>Note that when a const non-inline non-constexpr static data member is odr-used, a definition at namespace scope is still required, but it cannot have an initializer.</sup>

Comment: ok so for future, everytime I declare a static variable inside a class I need to define and initialize it outside the class? Or is there a way to do this within the class

Comment: @TheoWalton The const/inline static data member can be defined inside the class definition. See the link I posted for more informations.

Comment: If it is a simple type like a const integral, I believe you can define it right there.  Literally put an "= 0" after the declaration right in the header file.  I admit I forget the specific rules.   But for more complicated types, you generally need to put it in the .cpp file.

Comment: @songyuano:  What link?

Comment: @Joe Link added.